# Background-image too large even with backgound-size:cover;

Tags: css

my background-image is coming out too large and have tried pretty much everything, i want tear my hair out lol.

Here is my CSS:

```css
html {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2662116/pexels-photo-2662116.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: try to gave `height` on which element you are using `background-image` . might it will help you.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'too large'?

Answer (score 0):

```css
  body {
       width : 100%;
       height : 100%;
       background : url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2662116/pexels-photo-2662116.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
       background-size: cover
    }
```

Comment: I tested the code, there was no problem. please check it

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 